# sql server 2008 and 2005 on same machine?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I already have sql server 2008 installed and now need to install 2005 express as well. When I try this, the installation fails with: "An installation package for the product Microsoft SQL Server VSS Writer cannot be found" - any ideas anyone?

Comment: You can install multiple SQL Server instances on a single computer.  Mind that you aren't attempting to perform an in-place upgrade.  Also, you can set the compatibility level to 90 for SQL Server 2005 functionality.

Comment: are you using the default instance names for both or are you manually setting instance names?

Comment: That sounds like an issue with the installation package - make sure you run it locally (not from the network), and when it uncompresses it does so to a local location (not a temp drive like a usb flash drive). If that fails, redownload the installer package.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can definitely have both SQL Server 2005 (any edition) and SQL Server 2008 (any edition) on the same machine. But of course - you cannot have both be the default instance (which you access without specific instance name). Typically that's not a problem since the Express editions default to the `.\SQLEXPRESS` instance name. Just something to remember when installing.

**HOWEVER:** you need to make sure to **first** install your SQL Server 2005 and **then** the 2008 edition. It won't work the other way around, unfortunately.

So in your case: you'll need to first uninstall SQL Server 2008m, then install SQL Server 2005 Express and SQL Server 2008 on top of that again.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of! Oh well. - Thanks